Render a fixed sized rectangle inside a svg DOM
I want to draw some CAD like shapes in the Browser-DOM. SVG is a good way to go.
But for editing a shape I want draw a 'handle' - a fixed size rectangle. So zooming into the SVG via changing the viewBox attribute should not change its size.
I tried with:
<rect .... width="10px" height="10px" />

but that does not work.
Any ideas?

If it's just a rectangle you can use a very short line with stroke-linecap="square" and  vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"

when you change the viewBox change the size/position of the rectangle too.

You can get any shape to be non-scaling by defining it inside a marker and applying it to an unfilled, unstroked line, using non-scaling stroke and defining stroke width and fill within the marker. (The downside is that rendered markers have limited accessibility in the DOM).
